# Improvement with list stream HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

Is there a way of improving this method using list stream.

```
@Override
public HashMap<Long, Long> countSearchBetweenDates(OffsetDateTime startPeriod, OffsetDateTime endPeriod) {
    List<Tuple> results = this.repository.countBetweenDate(startPeriod, endPeriod);
    HashMap<Long,Long> companyCountMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(Tuple t : results){
        companyCountMap.put(t.get(0,Long.class), t.get(1, Long.class));
    }
    return companyCountMap;
}
```

I've tried it but I just can't get it to work because of the lambda operator.

```
 return results.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Tuple::get(0, Long.class), Tuple::get(1, Long.class));
```

The `Tuple::get(0, Long.class), Tuple::get(1, Long.class)` gets signaled as an error but IDE can't identify what is it.

Comment: As an aside: I would question the implementation of `public <T> T get(int index, Class<T> clazz)` in `Tuple`.

Comment: You can't send parameters this way in method reference. Use lambda exp for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you are using is not correct, the correct one should be :

```
return results.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(t -> t.get(0, Long.class), t -> t.get(1, Long.class));
```